# typescript set of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, collections, set

I am new in angular2 and typescript. I have a problem in creating an unique collection like Set<>. 
I want to avoid duplicate objects in a collection, for that purpose, try to use 
a set dataType like following code:

```
private cardItems = new Set<MyBean>([]);
```

MyBean is an object.

```
export class MyBean  {

  id:integer
  ownerId:integer
  ownerName:string
  img: string;

constructor() {

}
public equals(obj: MyBean) {
    console.log(obj.id);
    if (this.id == obj.id) {
        console.log(obj.id);
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    return true;
}

public hashCode(obj: MyBean) {
    return obj.id
}
```

}

but equals and hashCode does not run in this way.and I have duplicate objects in set.

What is the solution for implementing Set?

Many thanks

Comment: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: I'd consider writing my own array wrapper for this, can't be much code.

Comment: is your array wrapper   a loop through   array collection?

Answer (score 8):

How about extending the `Set` class and then overriding the `add` method:

```
interface SetItem {
    equals(other: SetItem): boolean;
}

class MySet<T extends SetItem> extends Set<T> {
    add(value: T): this {
        let found = false;
        this.forEach(item => {
            if (value.equals(item)) {
                found = true;
            }
        });

        if (!found) {
            super.add(value);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20SetItem%20%7B%0D%0A%09equals(other%3A%20SetItem)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MySet%3CT%20extends%20SetItem%3E%20extends%20Set%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09add(value%3A%20T)%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09let%20found%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.forEach(item%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09if%20(value.equals(item))%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09found%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09if%20(!found)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09super.add(value)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: "Add" method should work with O(1) or at least O(log n)
This solutions works with O(n)

Comment: What about Set.has() ? Does it work with this?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the solution for implementing Set

The JavaScript `Set` uses the same algorithm as `===` and there is no way to *override* that in your JavaScript class.

## Solution

You can use something that leverages an overridable function e.g. https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections uses `toString`.

Comment: thanks  for replying ,I have installed typescript-collections. but   I want to distinguish my object by its id.Because of that,  First added private recievers = new Collections.Set<MyBean>(); and after  adding a new object like:  this.recievers.add(contact); it contains <object object> dictionary.  In java , we can add instance of an object . but I did not find some examples like that in typescript.Would ypu pleae introduce some samples for adding a class object into Set?

Comment: I add object into set collection by following code ,but I don't think it is a good way:   this.recievers.add(new MyBean(contact.id, contact.firstName, contact.lastName, contact.mobile, contact.email));   I had to change  MyBean constructor and consequently other parts need change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a technique similar to comparing when 2 objects are similar:

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

This would, however, require you to `JSON.parse()` the members of your Set upon read, and would require some extra typing.

```
const obj1 = {id: 1, data: 'blue'};
const obj2 = {id: 2, data: 'red'};
const obj3 = {id: 1, data: 'blue'};
const myStringifiedObjSet: Set<string> = new Set([]);

myStringifiedObjSet.add(JSON.stringify(obj1));
  // Set { '{"id":1,"data":"blue"}' }
myStringifiedObjSet.add(JSON.stringify(obj2));
  // Set { '{"id":1,"data":"blue"}', '{"id":2,"data":"red"}' }
myStringifiedObjSet.add(JSON.stringify(obj3));
  // Set { '{"id":1,"data":"blue"}', '{"id":2,"data":"red"}' }

myStringifiedObjSet.has(JSON.stringify(obj1));
  // true

const objArray: object[] = Array.from(myStringifiedObjSet).map(el => JSON.parse(el));
  // [ { id: 1, data: 'blue' }, { id: 2, data: 'red' } ]
```