# TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new' while extending Set in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a class that extends a `Set` class and overide the implementations like below. I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950597/typescript-set-of-objects)

While the code below works

```
interface SetItem {
    equals(other: SetItem): boolean;
}

class MySet<T extends SetItem> extends Set<T> {
    add(value: T): this {
        let found = false;
        this.forEach(item => {
            if (value.equals(item)) {
                found = true;
            }
        });
        
        if (!found) {
            super.add(value);
        }
        
        return this;
    }
}
```

works at the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoTASUgW2QbwFgAoASAgEcBXOAGwGcAKAezAAtoAuNDbCHAJTcARs2a0IcEAG4SAXxIkEtOPXrIAsgE90YADwAVZBAAekEABN1uvjgB8xsxEvWMhh0TJwLFxgDc6KghuAyFkdmB1T1JSCTBkGGYqS2QAXgS6eghZMlII+gA6RKgAUUQ2RmBcNI8SGNJgGGR-QIgCyhoGStwBAQI6+sTkizTwqCCc+oVcuQFJ0gHG5oBCIcs+6Jj6KgAHaALvXwDaILmB6ZiBqAwqKBBwtkjJ6bkgA) . Calling

```
const mySet= new MySet<any>([])
```

breaks and throw the error

> TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'\n    at MySet.Set
> ()\n    at new MySet

It just doesn't work in my typescript despite working on the playground. Please how do I address this ? What am i missing ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your playground link is corrupt.

Comment: @jcalz pls try again.

Comment: You say it "doesn't work in my typescript". What is "your" TypeScript, exactly? If the issue is not easily reproducible in the Playground and is apparently specific to your environment, then you need to start there and identify the difference between your configuration and the Playground configuration.  What are your compiler settings?  What is your JavaScript runtime?  What is your build process?  Etc etc etc.  Ideally you will be able to figure out the problem yourself because it's hard for people to assist you from afar if the issue is in your environment.

Comment: @jcalz thank you so much. changing my eslint target to `es2017` from es5 seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I mean my `tsconfig.json` `target` from 'es5` to `es2017`